# Access UserDetails Object inside AuthenticationFailureHandler Spring Security 4.x

Tags: spring-security

I’m migrating an application from Spring Security 3 to 4.  The applications utilizes both form based username/password and smart card authentication.  It also has a custom *AuthenticationFailureHandler* that redirects the user to a particular page based on what type of error occurred and the roles associated to the user.  For example a locked exception should be handled differently for internal vs external users.

In Spring Security 3 the *org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker* used to place the UserDetails object into the *extraInformation* property of the *AuthenticationException* it threw. The custom *AuthenticationFailureHandler* we have utilized that to extract the roles from the user who failed authentication so it could handle the different user types appropriately:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
        throws IOException, ServletException {          
    User user = (User)exception.getExtraInformation();
    if(exception instanceof LockedException){
        if(user.hasAnyRole(Role.INTERNAL)){
            //Send to internal user page
        }else{
            //Send to external user page
        }
    }
}
```

However now with Spring Security 4, I’m not sure the best way to get the information about the user into the failure handler so I can appropriately route the request.  What would be considered the ‘best practice’ approach for this?

One approach is to extract the relevant information from the request (Either the form based username or the X509 cert) and then look up the roles using a database query but since that is already handled earlier in the Spring Security chain it seems like duplicating that effort in the failure handler isn’t the best approach.

Thanks